# Python inheritance dilemma for plugin

Tags: python, inheritance, sublime-text-plugin

*Although this question is in the context of a Sublime Text plugin, it is actually a question about Python object orientated design.*

Writing a Sublime Text plugin which contains 2 complimentary commands (with some shared functionality) has led me to a Python inheritance dilemma. Both options work perfectly well - I'm just unsure which is better OO design.

Option 1 - plugin commands use multiple inheritance:

```py
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class CopyLine():
    def copy_line(self):
        sels = self.view.sel()
        # Do some stuff
        return line_region

class CopyLineCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand, CopyLine):
    def run(self, edit):
        line_region = self.copy_line()
        # Do some stuff

class CutLineCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand, CopyLine):
    def run(self, edit):
        line_region = self.copy_line()
        # Do some stuff
```

Option 2 - plugin commands inherit the plugin `TextCommand` class from their parent:

```py
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class CopyLine(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def copy_line(self):
        sels = self.view.sel()
        # Do some stuff
        return line_region

class CopyLineCommand(CopyLine):
    def run(self, edit):
        line_region = self.copy_line()
        # Do some stuff

class CutLineCommand(CopyLine):
    def run(self, edit):
        line_region = self.copy_line()
        # Do some stuff
```

Both options have an aspect that I'm slightly uneasy about:

In *Option 1* the `copy_line()` method in the `CopyLine` class uses methods from the `sublime_plugin.TextCommand` class - e.g. the call shown to `view.sel()` - even though the `CopyLine` class has not inherited the `sublime_plugin.TextCommand` class.

In *Option 2* the `CopyLine` class inherits the `sublime_plugin.TextCommand` class even though it is not actually a plugin.

Which of these is better OO design? Is there an alternative design that I should use instead?

I've put the full code of both options in a [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/mattst/28a2fbacbe5780c1e0f0434951c102f7).

Comment: I wonder if this would be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/? However, not sure many people will know the ST API... Anyway, my opinion is that I would prefer 2 over 1, because accessing something "invisible" is never good ;) if somehow the class was instantiated directly, it would throw an exception. I think it would be even better to go down a third option and have one `TextCommand` class that handles the cut and the copy - depending on an argument passed in to it. (`def run(self, edit, **kwargs):`)

Comment: @KeithHall `# Do some stuff` => stub code => off-topic for code review. See the [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I would write `copy_line` as a function, which takes `view` as an argument instead of a method. This approach is also used in the most ST plugins I have seen so far.

Comment: @r-stein Thanks, that's a very good idea and exactly what I will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing r-stein's suggestion provides a solution to the plugin inheritance dilemma by using a non-OO design.

```py
import sublime, sublime_plugin

def copy_line(view):
    sels = view.sel()
    # Do some stuff
    return line_region

class CopyLineCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        line_region = copy_line(self.view)
        # Do some stuff

class CutLineCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        line_region = copy_line(self.view)
        # Do some stuff
```

The full code is in `Option_3_CopyAndCutLine.py` of this [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/mattst/28a2fbacbe5780c1e0f0434951c102f7).